# Is there any list-like structure that allows for insertion at arbitrary indexes, while preserving cache efficiency?

Tags: performance, data-structures

Vectors have good cache efficiency (elements with close indexes are placed close together in memory), but are inefficient for insertions in arbitrary positions. Lists have `O(1)` insertion in arbitrary positions (as long as you know the address of that position), but they have a terrible cache efficiency (elements are spread randomly across the heap).

Is there any data-structure with `O(1)` insertion in any index that keeps elements with near indexes in near places on memory?

Comment: `vector` is not inefficient at all. The `O(1)` of a list is *much* larger than an `O(1)` for a vector. It just says that the price for an operation is one bill, but doesn't say if it is $1 or $50 each.

Comment: You should give this a read: http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html

Comment: You seem to be mixing concepts from data structure theory with properties of specific implementations.  If you want to know specifically about the C++ STL, then remove the [c] and [data-structures] tags and add [stl].

Comment: I have removed both C++ and C tags. I'm not concerned with any of those in particular.

Comment: @Viclib, thanks for clarifying.  So I guess by "vector" you mean the thing whose name I more often see spelled "array", and by "list" you mean "*linked* list".  Yes?

Comment: By list I mean a linked list, by vector I mean a dynamic array which on this case is absolutely equivalent to an array, which I should have used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Placing list elements nearby is usually not a structure (vector, list) job, but an allocator job

> elements are spread randomly across the heap

for elements NOT to be spread out randomly across the heap, you have to use pool or fixed-size blocks allocation

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have both worst-case O(1) random-access insertion and also collocation of elements with similar indices.  If elements with similar indices must be located within O(1) units of each other then you can always insert enough elements at the same position so that the next insertion forces movement of O(n) other elements.  In fact, the number of elements you need to insert to force at least some movement is O(1) (because so is the spacing between near elements).

Answer (score 0):

Look into std::deque.  It mixes the properties of a vector and a list.  I believe it is implemented like a list but instead of having one node per allocation, it allocates a fixed number of nodes.

Comment: But a dequeue allows insertion only at the ends, not at arbitrary indices.

Comment: That's not correct.  It allows random access and insertion.  It has "fast" insertion at the ends.

Comment: There may be dequeue *implementations* that allow random access, but inasmuch as they do so, they are not operating as dequeues.  Inserting and removing at the ends is the defining property of a dequeue.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to a generic data structure called a dequeue? I'm referring to the specific std::deque that is part of the C++ standard library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque.

Comment: Indeed, what else would I be referring to than the standard data structure called a "dequeue", in context of a question tagged [data-structures] and [c] ([c++] tag notwithstanding)?  If you *mean* `std::dequeue`, then you should edit your answer to say so, because it is not assumable from context.

Comment: And in fact, now the OP has clarified that he is asking about data structures in general, indeed not specific implementations.  But I did remove my DV.

Comment: I added std::.  But note it is std::deque not std::dequeue.